# TFS 2010 - query needed to join three levels of WorkItems

Tags: tfs, workitem

I am just configuring some WorkItem Types to manage our releases - I've got quite far but I cannot see how to get a query to list what I need.

I have User Stories that have "Application Deployment" workitem types as children. Each Application Deployment represents an application to deploy. A User Story might require two applications to be changed. This is a parent/child relationship.

Separately to that, I also have "Release" workitem types. Each Release represents a day on which we will deploy our software. A Release will have several User Stories associated with it - I think using the Network topology of LinkType. This is because a User Story might actually be associated with more than one Release (for example, if we release to one territory first, and then to all remaining territories a week later).

What I would like is a query that lists what applications need to be released:-

- Release "14/03/2012"

  - Application Deployment "MyWebApp1"
  - Application Deployment "SomeWindowsService"

Release 14/03/2012
Application

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to return all the "Application Deployment" work item types associated with a given "Release".

In the query editor, you should be able to select your query type as "Tree of Work Items", and set your query to be `Work Item Type = Release`, and select linked work items that match the query `Work Item Type = Application Deployment`.

You can of course add other query filters.

This will give you roughly the following WIQL:

```
SELECT
    [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title],
    [System.AssignedTo], [System.State]
FROM WorkItemLinks WHERE
    (
        [Source].[System.TeamProject] = @project
        AND [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Release'
        AND [Source].[System.State] &lt;&gt; ''
    )
    AND ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward')
    AND [Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Application Deployment'
ORDER BY [System.Id]
mode(Recursive)
```

Comment: Hi Edward, yes you've got the nature of my problem right. I had tried "Tree of Work Items", but I think this is limited by the fact that the workitems must have a hierarchical relationship (parent/child). My User Stories have a "network" type topology connecting them to Release - this is because User Stories could be connected to several Releases.  Thanks for you help anyway!

Comment: Aha, I didn't entirely understand your linking at first.  Thanks for the clarification.